# run VBA macro on module variable change

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way to run a Macro in a Module each time a certain variable in the same Module changes?

It is important that the scope is restricted to the Module which I believe makes techniques such as "Workbook_SheetChange" unacceptable.

I have a function that I desire to return an initial value, and then trigger another sub to update other portions of the worksheet, but all the code must be contained in the single module

Comment: Set/change the variable via a Sub, and have that sub trigger your macro. Is it in a regular module, or a sheet/class ?  If in a class/sheet you can use a Property instead of a "bare" global.

Comment: I want to use a function to return an initial value to the worksheet and then trigger a macro after that has run as the UDF cannot modify other cells - that was unclear, sorry

I am working in a regular module

Comment: What does the macro you want to trigger do ?

Comment: I think you need to give more details as it's very unclear to me what you're trying to do.

Comment: a UDF cannot modify other cells, but a UDF can call another procedure that would modify the cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to go around this is

- Maintain a global variable which you would like to monitor, say every 10 seconds
- Run your monitoring `Sub` every 10 seconds using `Application.OnTime` (Google for how to use this)
- Your monitoring `Sub` should compare the variable with an older copy which is also kept as a Global variable.

  - If no change is detected, then do nothing.
  - If change is detected, then update the `PrevValue` to reflect the updated value of your monitored variable, and then call whatever other Subroutine you need to call.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed. Do you know if Application.OnTime is any significant drain on system resources? This module would likely be running at all times and I want to ensure it is not too taxing on the user system.

Comment: If I understand the method it would mean that the code is constantly running, but paused. Which means it would be unwise to do anything else in the file or on your computer unless the file is closed.

Comment: You won't even notice it (i.e. your monitoring SUB) if it's run every 15, 30 seconds. But the Sub that it calls might slow things down depending on how frequently changes take place. Best is to try and see. The last time I tried something like this, it was reasonably transparent to the user

Comment: @guitarthrower : Not really. It will run rather quietly in the background and if you're in the middle of updating a cell, etc. it'll just 'wait'. Try searching for the Application.Ontime Clock example on Google. Run it on your system and try playing with the spreadsheet simultaneously. You won't even notice it's presence

Comment: @guitarthrower, also, I'd be very happy to know more about non-polling ways to monitor arbitrary variables in any module. You can set up events but can't do that for any possible variable changing.

Comment: @hnk good to know about `Ontime`. About other options, I understand custom events can be created, but haven't done it myself. Chip Pearson has a great page [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx) - See the last section of the page. All based on Class Modules, which he also has a primer on [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Classes.aspx).

Comment: @guitarthrower agree about events. That is the most efficient way to do this but as I mentioned earlier since the OP wanted to monitor an arbitrary variable and not a class based property I thought this would work better for this specific problem. If I would implement this I would design the problem around event triggers

Comment: I assumed he was talking about worksheet and other built-in events. And not necessarily custom events and classes. Yours is a good option regardless.